# ASP.NET MVC - Any reason to use App_Themes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, app-themes

Is there any advantage to ASP.NET's `App_Themes` folder that could be taken advantage of in ASP.NET MVC, or is using them from the `Content` folder as normal the best way to handle resources like images, stylesheets, etc.

Does the fact that they're in the `App_Themes` folder add anything special to them?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App_Themes is for regular ASP.NET, not for MVC. The Themes system is built on top of ASP.NET's event model, which is not used in MVC.

Comment: Haven't looked back into this yet, thought perhaps there was some kind of caching or something that ASP.NET does, that might be usable? Don't know the theme stuff much, just used normal CSS before.. will accept this for now.